# Consultar Múltiplas Colunas no R

Tags: r

Tenho um DF e gostaria de consultar múltiplas colunas ao mesmo tempo em uma Tabela Auxiliar. Exemplo do DF:

```
MATRICULA <- c(123,456,789,111,222,333)
DIA_1 <- c('ARROZ','','ARROZ','','ARROZ','')
DIA_2 <- c('FEIJAO','','FEIJAO','','','FEIJAO')
DIA_3 <- c('BATATA','','BATATA','','BATATA','BATATA')
DIA_4 <- c('COUVE','COUVE','','COUVE','','COUVE')
DIA_5 <- c('BIFE','','BIFE','','BIFE','BIFE')
DADOS <- data.frame(MATRICULA,DIA_1,DIA_2,DIA_3,DIA_4,DIA_5)
```

Minha Tabela Auxiliar

```
AUXILIAR <- c('ARRROZ','FEIJAO')
TABELA_AUX <- data.frame(AUXILIAR)
```

Sendo assim, gostaria de consultar as 5 colunas ao mesmo tempo (DIA_1 a DIA_5) para verificar se a matricula consumiu algum alimento da Tabela Auxiliar (arroz **OU** feijao).

Como resultado, gostaria de ver a seguinte saída:

```
MATRICULA <- c(123,456,789,111,222,333)
DIA_1 <- c('ARROZ','','ARROZ','','ARROZ','')
DIA_2 <- c('FEIJAO','','FEIJAO','','','FEIJAO')
DIA_3 <- c('BATATA','','BATATA','','BATATA','BATATA')
DIA_4 <- c('COUVE','COUVE','','COUVE','','COUVE')
DIA_5 <- c('BIFE','','BIFE','','BIFE','BIFE')
VERIFICACAO <- c('SIM','NAO','SIM','NAO','SIM','SIM') 
RESULTADO <- data.frame(MATRICULA,DIA_1,DIA_2,DIA_3,DIA_4,DIA_5,VERIFICACAO)
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem várias maneiras. Aqui uma usando a função `apply`, com um `for` e com o pacote `dplyr`.

Só tinha postado a primeira que foi a única que consegui com os dados iguaizinhos ao que você mandou. As outras precisam que as entradas sejam caracteres e não fatores, o que se conserta fácil na entrada ou no código e que até faz mais sentido pelo jeito que os dados estão organizados.

```
MATRICULA <- c(123,456,789,111,222,333)
DIA_1 <- c('ARROZ','','ARROZ','','ARROZ','')
DIA_2 <- c('FEIJAO','','FEIJAO','','','FEIJAO')
DIA_3 <- c('BATATA','','BATATA','','BATATA','BATATA')
DIA_4 <- c('COUVE','COUVE','','COUVE','','COUVE')
DIA_5 <- c('BIFE','','BIFE','','BIFE','BIFE')
DADOS <- data.frame(MATRICULA,DIA_1,DIA_2,DIA_3,DIA_4,DIA_5)


AUXILIAR <- c('ARROZ','FEIJAO')
TABELA_AUX <- data.frame(AUXILIAR)

#### USANDO A FUNÇÃO APPLY

DIAS <- c("DIA_1","DIA_2","DIA_3","DIA_4","DIA_5")

VERIFICACAO_1 <- apply(DADOS[,DIAS],1 , function(x){ #aplica a função nas linhas
  if (any(x %in% AUXILIAR)) { #testa se os valores estão na auxiliar
    "SIM"} else "NAO" #cria o vetor de verificação
})

RESULTADO_1 <- data.frame(DADOS,
                          "VERIFICACAO" = VERIFICACAO_1)

### usando um for
#Pra esse método e pro próximo os dados tem que tá em character e não em factor
#use stringASFactors = F na importação ou as.character() nas colunas

DADOS <- data.frame(MATRICULA,DIA_1,DIA_2,DIA_3,DIA_4,DIA_5, stringsAsFactors = F)

Numero_linhas <- dim(DADOS)[1]
VERIFICACAO_2 <- rep(0, Numero_linhas)

for(i in 1:Numero_linhas){
  VERIFICACAO_2[i] <-  ifelse(any(DADOS[i,DIAS] %in% AUXILIAR),
         "SIM", "NAO")
}


RESULTADO_2 <- data.frame(DADOS,
                          "VERIFICACAO" = VERIFICACAO_2)


### usando dplyr
#Se a entrada for character que nem a de cima
#Cria direto a tabela resultado

library(dplyr)

DIAS <- quo(c(DIA_1,DIA_2,DIA_3,DIA_4,DIA_5)) #permite que o dplyr entenda os nomes das colunas

RESULTADO_3 <- DADOS %>% 
  rowwise() %>% #faz a operação nas linhas
  mutate(VERIFICACAO = ifelse(any(!!(DIAS) %in% AUXILIAR),
                              "SIM", "NAO") #cria a coluna de verificação
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() #separa o grupos de linhas feitos por rowWise()


#testando se são iguais a referencia
VERIFICACAO <- c('SIM','NAO','SIM','NAO','SIM','SIM') 
VERIFICACAO == VERIFICACAO_1
VERIFICACAO == VERIFICACAO_2
VERIFICACAO == RESULTADO_3$VERIFICACAO
```

Comment: Caro Jorge, obrigado! Porém, da maneira que você colocou a coluna "VERIFICACAO"  indica que ela não foi construída de forma automática (vc já informa os resultados). O meu problema seria como construir, de forma automática, a coluna "VERIFICACAO". Além disso, percebi que a sua query varre todas a linhas do arquivo, porém eu não posso fazer isso, tenho que limitar somente a estas colunas (DIA_1 até DIA_5). Conseguiria me ajudar novamente após estas observações? Grato.

Comment: Eu edito com umas modificações. Só que eu criei a coluna de forma automática, usando DADOS e a AUXILIAR. No final eu só criei uma coluna com o nome "VERIFICACAO" porque é um nome melhor que "VERIFICACAO_1", mas não utilizei a variável de exemplo. Deixei ela aí só pra motivo de teste.

Comment: Fiz as edições. Coloquei um vetor de filtro para a colunas e deixei o teste pro final, pra deixar mais claro que o vetor `VERIFICACAO` não entrou na tabela.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez. Você disse que tem outras maneiras além dessa com apply. Poderia me mostrar outra sugestão, se possível? Grato.

Comment: Pronto, fiz mais uma edição